# Extra padding in some iOS devices

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In some iOS devices, there is an extra padding in the bottom. I tested it in some iOS simulators (including a simulator with the same specs of the device of the first image) and Android emulators and there is no padding in any of them.

[image]

This is the expected behaviour:

[image]

What kind of widgets can cause this unexpected behaviour in some specific devices?

Comment: Are you working with any `SafeArea`? It is the first thing that came to mind when I read your question, since it is used to add padding in bezel-less phones.

Comment: Not using SafeArea, but this padding is in the middle of a Column widget wich is inside of a SingleChildScrollView, so I guess the SafeArea would not affect the inner widgets, maybe am I wrong?

Comment: No, `SafeArea` should not affect inner widgets, but sometimes it can get tricky, depending on where you place it. Can you provide a minimal sample code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot reproduce this error, but looks like it's happening in the iPhone XS (but it not occurs in the iOS simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the Flutter SDK version fixed the problem.